# How to have flink check point/savepoint backup on multiple data center

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have flink application which will run on a node in DC-1 (Data Center 1), we are planning to have savepoint and checkpoint state backup with HDFS or AMAZON-S3. The support in my org for both HDFS and S3 is that it does not replicate data written to DC-1 to DC-2 (They are working on it but time line is large). With this in mind, is there a way to have flink checkpoint/savepoint be written to both DC by flink itself somehow ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no such mechanism in Flink. Usually, it's not the data processing pipelines responsibility to assert that data gets backed.  The easiest workaround for that would be to create a CRON job that periodically copies checkpoints to DC-2.